# flutter Theme Dark/Light - not working when I use style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5

Tags: flutter, themes, darkmode

I am implementing a Theme Dark & Light.

If I use this

```
title: Text("${singleProject.name}",),style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
```

The text stay black even when I switch to Dark.

If I use this code

```
title: Text("${singleProject.name}",),
```

the text is changing his color depending if I am on light or dark mode.
The problem in that case I can not use the font and the size I want for all my app.

Please, can you help?

text_theme

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class TTextTheme {

  static TextTheme lightTextTheme = TextTheme(

    subtitle1: GoogleFonts.openSans (color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 13.0),

    ///For subtitle Drawer Menu
    bodyText1: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0),

    bodyText2: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 13.0),
    headline6: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),

    ///For AppBar title
    headline1: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),

    ///For Title Drawer Menu
    headline2: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.blue[900],
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13.0),

    ///For tasks & Projects lists
    headline3: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,),

   /* headline4: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,
        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        decorationThickness: 2.85,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
*/
    headline5: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,),

  );

  static TextTheme darkTextTheme = TextTheme(

      subtitle1: GoogleFonts.openSans (color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 13.0),

      ///For subtitle Drawer Menu
      bodyText1: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0),

      bodyText2: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 13.0),
      headline6: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),


      ///For AppBar title
      headline1: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),

      ///For Title Drawer Menu
      headline2: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.blue[900],
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13.0),

      ///For tasks & Projects lists
      headline3: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,),

      headline4: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,
          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
          decorationThickness: 2.85,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),

    headline5: GoogleFonts.montserrat (color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 16.0,),

  );
}
```

theme_provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_gtd_20220804/theme/text_theme.dart';

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.system;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme (bool isOn){
    themeMode = isOn? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light ;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyThemes {

  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(

    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    dividerColor: Colors.grey[300],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    textTheme:  TTextTheme.darkTextTheme,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    bottomAppBarColor: Colors.black,


  //  fontFamily: 'arimo',
  );



  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(

    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    dividerColor: Colors.grey[300],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    textTheme:  TTextTheme.lightTextTheme,
   // fontFamily: 'arimo',
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    bottomAppBarColor: Colors.white,
    // accentColor: Colors.red,
    // accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    // colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
    // primaryColor: Colors.blue,

  );


  /*final menuTitleText = const TextTheme(
    subtitle2: 10,
  );
*/

}
```

Main

```
return MaterialApp(
                themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
                theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
                darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
```

I also try

```
class MyThemes {

  static final darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(

   // primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    dividerColor: Colors.grey[300],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    textTheme:  TTextTheme.darkTextTheme,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    bottomAppBarColor: Colors.black,
  //  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans Japanese',
  //  fontFamily: 'arimo',
  );
```

Then, with

```
 Text(singleDocument.name!,                           style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
```

Now, when I switch from light to dark mode, the text remain black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're implementing the `TextTheme` all by yourself, this leads you to specify every single property manually in order to get your expected result, instead of specifying `ThemeData()`, consider using the predefined `ThemeData` factory constructors such as `ThemeData.light()`, `ThemeData.dark()`, then override their properties with the `copyWith`, like this:

```
   // You need here to specify all properties by yourself
   static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
   // ...


   // Here you take the predefined dark theme and override its properties
   static final darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
   // ...
```

you can do the same thing for the light mode using `ThemeData.light().copyWith(/*...*/)`

Comment: Thank you. Please, can you tell me more? I am not sure to get it properly.

Comment: in the `darkTheme` declaration, instead of using the `ThemeData(/* Your properties */)`, replace it with `ThemeData.dark().copyWith(/* Your properties  */)`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but it is not working properly. I update my code to show.

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this problem because you're not using the right context in your app. To fix the issue you just have to do this

```
void main() {
 runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
  theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
  darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
  home: MyApp(),
 ),
);
```